# Setting jQuery UI Progress Bar from HTML Element Contents

Tags: jquery, html

I've added a progress bar from jQuery UI plug-in and I don't want to control it from value like this (as is the default setting):

```
$("#progressBar").progressbar({
  value: 30.59
});
```

Instead I want to control it directly from my HTML. I have this code in my HTML:

```
<span class="counter">30.59</span>
<div id="progressBar" ></div>
```

And this code in my JS:

```
var counter = $(".counter");   
$("#progressBar").progressbar({
 value: counter
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text) of the `.counter` element:

```
var counterValue = parseFloat($(".counter").text());
$("#progressBar").progressbar({ value: counterValue });
```

Comment: Right, but it doesn't work with the progressbar(jQuery UI) I get blank.

Answer (score 1):

The code `$(".counter")` returns a jQuery span object, which assigned to a progress bar value is no use to you.

The code you need is:

```
var couterValue = parseFloat($(".counter").text());
$("#progressBar").progressbar({ value: counter });
```

Another thing to think about is **when** this code runs.

If this code is executed only once on page load, the progress bar will only show the initial value for the span object.

I can't imagine this code being much help to you, as whatever is updating the counter span tag will also need to trigger a copy into the progress bar and therefore should put the value there directly.

As far as I know you can not capture events for text changing on DOM objects that are not form controls.